# The Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY) principle in documentation

Tags: documentation, dry

Dave Thomas, the author of the [Don't Repeat Yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) principle [said](https://www.artima.com/articles/orthogonality-and-the-dry-principle):

> DRY says that every piece of system knowledge should have one
> authoritative, unambiguous representation. Every piece of knowledge in
> the development of something should have a single representation. A
> system's knowledge is far broader than just its code. It refers to
> database schemas, test plans, the build system, even documentation.

I have difficulty to understand how it applies to programming code documentation.

Java API has the [java.util.Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html) class with the *copyOf* method that is overloaded 7 times. The 8 methods can be documented in two ways containing the same information. The first way describes all overloaded methods using a single description, highlighting the differences between overloads. The second way describes each overloaded method using a separate description. Below are both ways - I bolded the differences in the content. The second way was literally copied from the API documentation of the java.util.Arrays class.

**Is the second way compliant with the DRY principle?** In my opinion it isn't, because it contains text which was copied multiple times, then, additionally, minor modifications were made to each copy. The same information can be provided in one text, which is almost eight times shorter. But I am not sure if I understand correctly the definition of the DRY principle. **What are the "pieces of system knowledge" in this case? Do they have single, unambiguous, authoritative representation in the quoted documentation?**

## Documentation of the overloaded copyOf() methods - 1st way

> ```java
> public static byte[]    copyOf​(byte[]    original, int newLength)
> public static short[]   copyOf​(short[]   original, int newLength)
> public static int[]     copyOf​(int[]     original, int newLength)
> public static long[]    copyOf​(long[]    original, int newLength)
> public static float[]   copyOf​(float[]   original, int newLength)
> public static double[]  copyOf​(double[]  original, int newLength)
> public static char[]    copyOf​(char[]    original, int newLength)
> public static boolean[] copyOf​(boolean[] original, int newLength)
> ```
>
> Copies the specified array, truncating or padding with **the default
> values** (if necessary) so the copy has the specified length. For all
> indices that are valid in both the original array and the copy, the
> two arrays will contain identical values. For any indices that are
> valid in the copy but not the original, the copy will contain **the
> default value**. Such indices will exist if and only if the specified
> length is greater than that of the original array.
>
> **The following table lists default values for given type of array elements:**
>
> | type | the default value of type |
> | --- | --- |
> | `byte`, `short`, `int`, `long` | `0` |
> | `float`, `double` | `0.0` |
> | `char` | null character `('\u0000')` |
> | `boolean` | `false` |
>
> Parameters:
>
> - original - the array to be copied
> - newLength - the length of the copy to be returned
>
> Returns: a copy of the original array, truncated or padded with **the
> default values** to obtain the specified length
>
> Throws:
>
> - NegativeArraySizeException - if newLength is negative
> - NullPointerException - if original is null
>
> Since: 1.6

## Documentation of the overloaded copyOf() methods - 2nd way

> ```java
> public static byte[] copyOf​(byte[] original, int newLength)
> ```
>
> Copies the specified array, truncating or padding with **zeros** (if
> necessary) so the copy has the specified length. For all indices that
> are valid in both the original array and the copy, the two arrays will
> contain identical values. For any indices that are valid in the copy
> but not the original, the copy will contain **(byte)0**. Such indices
> will exist if and only if the specified length is greater than that of
> the original array.
>
> Parameters:
>
> - original - the array to be copied
> - newLength - the length of the copy to be returned
>
> Returns: a copy of the original array, truncated or padded with
> **zeros** to obtain the specified length
>
> Throws:
>
> - NegativeArraySizeException - if newLength is negative
> - NullPointerException - if original is null
>
> Since: 1.6
>
> ```java
> public static short[] copyOf​(short[] original, int newLength)
> ```
>
> Copies the specified array, truncating or padding with **zeros** (if
> necessary) so the copy has the specified length. For all indices that
> are valid in both the original array and the copy, the two arrays will
> contain identical values. For any indices that are valid in the copy
> but not the original, the copy will contain **(short)0**. Such indices
> will exist if and only if the specified length is greater than that of
> the original array.
>
> Parameters:
>
> - original - the array to be copied
> - newLength - the length of the copy to be returned
>
> Returns: a copy of the original array, truncated or padded with
> **zeros** to obtain the specified length
>
> Throws:
>
> - NegativeArraySizeException - if newLength is negative
> - NullPointerException - if original is null
>
> Since: 1.6

*and so on for: int, long, float, double, char, boolean.* It is *exactly* the same text, eight times, where only the bold parts are different.

Comment: Are you sure the documentation was copy&pasted? I am not very familiar with the J2SE API, but I know the Scala API documentation quite well, and there, they use macros to generate documentation for similar methods. So, the content is only written once, and parameterized with the different types.

Comment: @JörgWMittag, it is in the same form in the API documentation on https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html, and in the source code in Arrays.java file. But I don't know if Oracle generates Arrays.java file or not.

Comment: If you can get access to the 2019 edition of The Pragmatic Programmer, read the chapter on DRY, it's explained pretty well there. The main objection is that people tend to repeat implementation details in the documentation (e.g. the comment says "if the account is in overdraft for more than 3 days, charge $10 for each day", which is an internal detail, and already can be seen from the code (example from the book). This is often a result of silly company policies mandating that all functions must have doc comments. Another common thing is something like `amount += 10; // increment by 10`

Comment: There's always a balance between practicality and ideology. Even the great Java isn't perfect. I haven't looked but I'd venture a guess that PHP, even most programming languages, don't have documentation perfectly adhering to DRY theory. Probably a correlation with age of the language too.

Comment: @DocBrown: The length of the quote clearly shows a possible problem with DRY. With all 8 methods listed and the differences highlighted, they can be easily compared. Maybe the differences justify that there is a separate text for each overload in the API documentation? The documentation excerpt is now marked as a quote so it's easier to read the question.

Comment: @DocBrown: I shortened the citation to two examples

Comment: @iwis: reads better now, I took the freedom to add a sentence at the end, to make it more clear what's going on here.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović I don't think your two documentation examples are equivalent.  The first (overdraft) explains the intention of the code.  They code may or may not implement that intention.  The second (increment) is a  description of of the mechanics of the code.  I happily accept the former, but in general the latter should die (with exceptions for unusual code/methodologies).  I'll also plug an answer of mine on SO about coments: https://stackoverflow.com/a/308930/31326

Comment: javadoc is intended to have canonical documentation on every method for programmers to look up directly.   Hence _that_ is the important part.

Comment: @PeterM - I understand what you're saying; I see now that it's not too clear from the way I wrote it (sry, I was trying to fit it all in a single comment), but the "overdraft" example (from the book) is just a part of a larger function that has a more high-level intent, so the comment *is* describing the internal mechanics (although, it could be valid if the corresponding code was extracted into a function of its own). It's a part of an example where a doc comment covers the implementation almost line by line, and this particular comment was not a description at the appropriate level of abstr.

Comment: @PeterM - Also, one of the concerns the authors mention there is that these sort of comments, being way too specific, tend to become out of sync with the code. Another one is about  the values "3 days" and "$10" being "hardcoded" into the doc comment, which is a valid concern under the assumption that this sort of policy is not unlikely to change, or that it's reasonable, in the specific context of the system, for these values to be(come) configurable.

Comment: I guess I should, for the sake of clarity, be more explicit about the purpose of my original remark. The OP found an example where a doc comment was repeated across several functions. This sort of thing is more a symptom of the (perhaps apparent) nonDRY-ness of the code itself; I was trying to point out that Dave Thomas' remark was more about DRY violations across a piece of code and its corresponding documentation text (same knowledge repeated in two different forms), rather than across two documentation entries (where the source of repetition actually lies within the associated code).

Answer (score 30):

**About this specific problem:**
From a technical perspective for me, the documentation of Array.copyOf is DRY, from my Developer perspective it is not.

The relevant information of each method are the input parameters, the output, the special behavior for different lengths, the possible errors.
Those are nearly identical over all overloaded implementations. From a technical perspective, each overloaded method could in theory behave differently. That means even if that is not the case now, it could in the future. Therefore those information are the same, but not identical. Therefor "repeating" it is absolutely correct and is not violating the DRY principle.

On the other side, the intention of the whole method is to provide the absolutely same functionality for different data types. That means, the intention is, that those functions will evolve equally. Then those information are not just the same, but identical. Therefore from this perspective the documentation is violating the DRY principle.

**When WE are in such a situation to decide how to write a documentation and should we follow DRY or not:**

The question is what we want to achieve.
DRY is not a goal. It's a strategy to achieve a goal.

If you want that you don’t have to change much in the documentation, when your code changes, then use DRY.

*But*, as in code, this comes with a cost. It means you will have to write more "generic" documentation. Generics are in most cases more complex, that means harder to understand. Hmm that is violating the [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle#In_software_development) (keep it simple, stupid) principle now? Yep :-(

Therefore the first question is, what do you want to achieve. And then you have to balance the principles.

For example, if I have some code that will change very rarely, and people will often need some functions of it, but rarely all of them, then I would prefer the approach with describing each function independently. It makes understanding easier and the additional maintaining effort is not that important, because my expectation is that there will not be so many changes.

If my code changes often, and/or most people will need the whole thing and not only parts, then a more condensed, generic style would be appropriate.

Therefore, in my eyes we should *know* those principles. And never completely ignore them. But it's not about following a principle blindly, but about realising which principle will support me in the current context the best to achieve my specific goals.
In my experience, the hardest part is to determine good, precise, goals. But that's another topic. :-)

**Updated** (added the initial part) because the question was sharpened. Thanks @iwis for the question.

Comment: Exactly. If humans were computers then completely DRY documentation would work well. But humans forget things and have a small cache so it is great to repeat useful information so that it is readily at hand where needed. Another example... In perfectly DRY documentation there would be no examples because examples repeat the information that is already encoded in the docs.

Comment: DRY isn't intended to prevent the same information being presented in different ways. It's to avoid situations where different parts of the documentation lose their anchor to the shared underlying information. The documentation can then become inconsistent. A bit like Census data summary tables -- they are repeating information found in the base data, but are useful for understanding as long as they remain bound to the raw data and can be automatically regenerated if the raw data changes.

Comment: @Felix I guess you could say that humans are WET (we encourage thinking) rather than DRY, which is not very generative.

Comment: Added an initial paragraph to answer the sharpened question of @iwis

Comment: I can recall coming across this "DRY documentation" style and hating it. You want to know what this function does, but the documentation won't tell you until you read through the tutorial for the entire library. It can even be something as simple as forwarding arguments in Python. "Unknown parameters will be passed to the transport." Okay? What the heck is a transport and what parameters does it accept? Oh there are different transports. Which one am I using, and what parameters does it accept? And then the transport accepts parameters for the underlying socket library...

Comment: `The question is what we want to achieve. DRY is not a goal. It's a strategy to achieve a goal.` This.

Answer (score 20):

Lets start with the `copyOf` example:

> Is the second way compliant with the DRY principle?

**No, it is not.** The similarities between these methods and their intended behaviour are way too obvious to assume they were caused just by incident, and if Oracle will ever have to change something in these docs, or translate them to a new language, or add some specifics for a new Java compiler version, they will have to do it eight times, not just one. However, I am pretty sure Oracle does not care:

- they have probably enough resources for maintaining the documentation in the current form and keep it in a consistent state.
- for such old and widely used framework methods, changes in behaviour are not to be expected to happen frequently, that would break too many existing applications.
- a documentation where developers can quickly find what they are looking for is probably more important for them than staying DRY.

However, the specific example from this question is probably not a typical one, hence it should not be taken as a general archetype for one's own documentation. As I wrote in a comment, the implementation code itself is duplicated most probably for two reasons

- lack of generics in Java at the time when `copyOf()` was initially placed in the library
- performance (array copying in a widely used general purpose lib of a standard framework should be as fast as possible, and Java's standard implementation of generics, which uses type erasure, isn't probably the best foundation for really fast `copyOf` implementation)

So this specific example aside, when is it a good idea to keep documentation DRY even when methods don't look so uniform?

In my experience, it not uncommon that a certain set of methods inside a library can share a common concept, a common convention, or certain common properties. Examples for this are often cross cutting concerns, like

- naming conventions indicating certain meaning,
- usage of a certain unit system for certain parameters,
- transactional behaviour for a certain group of methods or classes,
- debugging behaviour, logging behavior, error handling bahaviour,
- assumptions we can make or should not make about side effects,
- usage / meaning of certain frequently used terms from the domain, which occur in the API in several places.

Occasionally, we find an internal method with a lot of parameters, and an API which provides several different public entry points to it (often overloads), for simplification of usage, specific default parameters etc. This can guarantee a consistency in behaviour for all the different entry points.

Repeating such commonalities in each method's documentation over and over again can obviously lead to maintenance problems, just like non-DRY code leads to maintenance problems when something has to be changed afterwards. So how is this solved in documentation?

The standard solution here is write down the commonalities only in one place. In the doc section of all other methods where they also apply, one can place a link or reference to the place where the common parts are documented. For example, Javadoc has a [link feature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2558727), which allows exactly this.

The downside of this is that if one overuses links and references, documentation can become pretty hard to read and understand. Jumping back and forth between two places in a document can become pretty annoying. Hence it is important to find the right balance between the part of the documentation which is written for each method individually (but may repeat certain things), and the careful usage of links / references to things which shall not be repeated.

Comment: Hm. These are all arrays of primitive types, not of references. Can Java generics handle them now?

Comment: The problem is not the lack of generics, but that Java still treats primitive types as something separate from reference types, so it needed separate methods (or an untyped method, like the old `System.arraycopy`, which just takes an `Object` (which must be an array of some kind)).

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann: as I wrote, the problem *today* is not the lack of generics, but performance (my second point on the list).

Comment: I don't agree that this is a rare example. Yes the exact circumstance is rare, but in a language without default values for parameters (or languages like C# where using default parameters is ill-advised for compat reasons in frameworks and libraries) having overloads that provide defaults for some values is very common. You could link to the method that provides all parameters and rely on the documentation there, but that makes for an awful user experience (I want to see the documentation for the parameters a method takes without having to jump around!).

Comment: (That said I agree with the wider point about defining cross-cutting concerns only once).

Comment: Your first bullet point is invalid, even with modern java generic, you cannot make only a single method. A `short[]` is not an `Object[]`. Even if you wanted to make a method(ignoring the horrible performance, you would fail)

Comment: @Ferrybig: when I get you right, your critics seem to be badly worded. I guess wanted to tell me that the (formerly) first bullet point is still valid today, not that it is invalid.

Comment: It is kind of a reversal of immutability: make as many copies of something as you like if it will *not* be changing.

Answer (score 15):

You shouldn't seek to make your documentation more DRY than your code.

Documentation is random access. People don't generally read it straight through. So if someone happens to look for the seventh override of a function, they should be able to quickly find everything they need to use it. It's reasonable to assume a user learning how to use a method might read the documentation for a class as well, but you shouldn't make them find the documentation for all "similar" methods.

If you feel your documentation is too repetitive, **fix the code**. Make better abstractions. Factor common concepts out. If your language isn't expressive enough to avoid duplication, you shouldn't feel bad if your docs match. The duplication is serving a useful purpose in that case. Code is read *significantly* more frequently than written, so it's more than okay to optimize for the reading case.

Comment: This point of view does not convince me. If code is implemented in a DRY fashion or not is an implementation detail from the APIs point of view. For example, if code which was once DRY, with a non-repetitive documentation,  is made repetitive for the sole purpose of optimization, why should the documentation then be changed?

Comment: "If your map doesn't match the terrain, trust the terrain." (or change it)

Comment: @DocBrown for this `Documentation is random access` and because sometimes, the implementation details matter. For example, `isEmpty()`. This's the kind of function where implementation details matter because conditions vary from type to type. `isEmpty(array)` and `isEmpty(String)` have different semantics. For example, how many times have you wondered if "null" is checked as "empty" or it cast an exception? And whitespace? Does the method cast `trim` before checking it out? And tabs? What about collections? What makes a map to be empty? its length? the null entries? Etc.

Comment: @Laiv: that's not my point. These examples are not showing cases where DRY code was made repetitive for optimization purposes.

Answer (score 6):

The DRY principle applies equally to documentation.

On the other hand, there might be shortcomings in the tooling used in the documentation process that make it hard or impossible to create the documentation in the format of your first example.

For example, the method documentation in Java is commonly generated from Javadoc comments in the source code. I am not sure if there is a way to write a Javadoc comment that is recognized by the tooling as applying to multiple different methods. And also, such a single comment block for multiple methods can make it harder to tell for developers looking at the code if a particular method is properly and correctly documented or not. So that are some forces working against DRY documentation.

In the end, you will have to find a balance between the desire to have DRY documentation and the forces working against it. Different people/organizations will put what is optimal for them at different points.

Comment: Applying a single comment to multiple different methods is possible in C#. On reddit.com/r/learnjava/ I read the opinion: "Overloaded methods are not the same methods. Which means they are not violating DRY." I am afraid that due to tool limitations, programmers of different languages may say that my example violates the DRY rule, or doesn't violate it. Is there reasoning I can use in the argumentation, regardless of the capabilities of the documentation tools? "The documentation is copied several times => violation of the DRY rule" - or is it more sophisticated?

Comment: My reasoning for *calling* something a DRY violation would be "The documentation is copied several times and the copies need to be kept consistent". However, tooling and culture factors will affect the ability and willingness of people to *make* the documentation more DRY.

Comment: @iwis: this reddit opinion is missing the point, even differently named methods can violate the DRY principle (and overloaded methods may or may not violate it). It depends on if there is a (part of) the behaviour which must be consistent (or not).

Comment: Tooling is an important part of the question, as mentioned by @Bart van Ingen Schenau. In my documentation tool, we can abstract portions of code and use them in multiple places that are either identical, or substantially similar (then we use conditions to keep track of how they are different, when they differ). So in the documentation _source_ there is only one file that contains that information. However, that file may be included in several different pages, if needed, to ensure the user has all the relevant information when they are learning about a feature or following a procedure.

Answer (score 3):

**From a DRY perspective**

The second one is correct.

A common misunderstanding of DRY is that it applies to *expressions* of concepts, rather than to the *concepts themselves*.

This mostly seems to come from programmers being told that they shouldn't copy/paste things and thinking that means any sufficiently similar representations of concepts should be consolidated. This leads to people going on crusades in the codebase to rid it of any similar pieces of code.
But this is wrong. When applying the SRP *it's perfectly acceptable to have multiple classes containing essentially identical code as long as they are describing different system concepts*.

In this case you've noticed that several system concepts (descriptions of methods) that can be expressed in a similar way. This is true, but by consolidating them you're mixing together multiple system concepts into a single, more complex, expression.

**From a design perspective**

Like any data structure the design of documentation depends on how you anticipate it will be updated and read. The downside of the first approach is that previously separate concepts are now mixed together in the documentation, which changes how they can be updated/read.

Consider the Single Responsibility Principle (SRP) here:

If any of those methods change their behaviour (unlikely in this specific case, but more likely in less platformy classes) it will require making a documentation change that will affect many classes. Changing the description of any one method is now harder because the updater will need to consider the impact of their change all the methods that the description applies to.

I would expect the most common operation will be someone looking up documentation for a method (rather than creating or updating). In that case it's a fair assumption they want be shown *only* the documentation relevant to that specific method, not other methods which happen to be similar. I certainly wouldn't want to have to look up tables and spent effort to disentangle the behaviour of other methods to get the information I want.

Comment: To my understanding, the different "copyOf​" overloads shown in the example *are* part of the same system concept. I would actually would have expected them to be implemented only once with Java's generics - but I guess that API exists longer than Java has generics, and the performance impact using generics for an API which is intended to provide a blazingly fast copy function would not be acceptable for lots of scenarios.

Comment: @DocBrown I agree that for a generic method it would be reasonable to have a single piece of documentation for the method. However, I think the code and the documentation range over different systems. This is subtle, but I think what constitutes a system concept in the code and what constitutes a system concept in the documentation of that code differ. In this case the language limitations of java resulted in multiple similar methods being required to express a single domain-system concept, which in turn has given rise to multiple separate code-system concepts in the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

The second style is far nicer for the *end user* of the documentation. Especially since documentation is almost used in "reference" mode, rather than in "novel" mode. If I'm trying to accomplish a task or understand a behavior, I'll consult the documentation for a particular function to see exactly how that function works. I don't care about the other overloads of that function, so I don't really want to have to expend the mental overhead to read everything, remove the irrelevant bits, and extract the relevant information. I'd much rather just go straight to the documentation about the overload of interest.

Now, you certainly have a point that the second style is to be feared and avoided by the developer (or whoever is writing/maintaining the documentation). It's a nightmare for all the same reasons that repetitive code is a nightmare.

So, a conflict emerges; what to do? It's better to have *correct* and up-to-date information than it is to have maximally convenient information, so, all else being equal, the maintainer of the documentation has to win out in this conflict over the consumer of the documentation.

But, there doesn't have to be a conflict. Just as we write source code which is then run through tools to generate final binaries—and "DRY" doesn't care whether these tools produce output that is DRY—we can write documentation that is designed to be run through tools to generate the final documents. **Armed with a tool, you don't have to choose between the first and second style. You can write the first style, and the tool can generate the second style.** Therefore, this is what you should do. Use a tool that essentially functions as a documentation compiler/generator, and get the best of both worlds.

Comment: If you only want to understand code written, instead of writing or modifying it, sure, only the overload called is relevant. Still, if you know any other overload, or need to know one later, having them described together helps even in that situation. Manually finding relevant differences is a pita.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, documentation should be dry, in so far as things which are used and look identical except for trivial differences (types mostly, though they should still follow an obvious pattern, as the principle of least surprise demands) should be documented only once together.

And no, that the documentation is only *written* once is nearly completely uninteresting, if it has to be *read* multiple times. DRY applies to what the consumer interacts with too, not only with what the provider does to create it.

No in so far as there should be enough examples to demonstrate use of the API, and as a starting-point to doing things, and those are obviously repeating information.

Also, higher-level overviews can be extremely useful in exploring what something is about, what it could be used for, why it is as it is, and thus understanding capabilities and limitations. They summarize and set the details into context, thus per se repeating information.

---

Unfortunately, doc-comments and similar systems while quite good for documenting each entity (type, member, whatever) in isolation, are much harder to pretty useless for that.

At least merging the documentation of a group of entities defined together (same file, top of same scope) is not too hard to implement, even if each entity gets an additional notes-section. The first entity would add a new doc-comment like `merge`, while the others replace theirs. Merging those notes where appropriate under the same heading can get arbitrarily difficult though.

Linking to commonalities while far easier to implement, doesn't get rid of the repetition, and makes each part harder to read.

Answer (score 1):

The question is illustrated with an example where a method has multiple overloads with different signatures. But there's another example in the Java world, namely method overriding in subclasses. Should the Javadoc in a subclass repeat what's in the superclass?

In this case the Javadoc tooling gives you the option of avoiding the repetition, and the generated documentation for the subclass will pick up the details for the overridden method automatically. But that's not a perfect solution, because (a) documentation has two audiences, the user of the API and the maintainer of the code, and (b) you often want to say something more about the behaviour of an overriding method that can't be inferred from the generic information in the superclass.

Someone mentioned Scala documentation being generated from macros, and such a mechanism would be a great addition to the Javadoc toolset. But in the absence of such a mechanism, I think you have to treat the user of the API as your primary audience, and that means repeating yourself where necessary.

Comment: `@InheritDoc` is a thing.

Answer (score 1):

Programming principles are observations made by experienced, smart developers that have decided to distill some fundamental truth of programming for the rest of us to use as a rule of thumb. However, principles are more "very strong suggestions," not "immutable laws of the universe."

DRY is a rule to live by, not a rule to die by. So are KISS (*Keep It Simple, Stupid*), POLA (*Principle of Least Astonishment*), SOLID (*Single Responsibility Open-Closed, Liskov Substitution, Interface Segregation, Dependency Inverson*), etc. When we choose a principle to prioritize, we may sacrifice others. POLA may violate DRY, and DRY may sacrifice KISS, and SOLID may violate almost every other principle, although still important.

I would argue that, if most developers found the exact method they needed faster, on average, using the second form of the documentation, then it would be superior, as it implements POLA while sacrificing DRY. This is my opinion, and others will surely differ, as each person holds a set of values that informs their preferences.

---

That said, the second form of the documentation is definitely not DRY, but that may be acceptable if it allows the average developer to find and understand the purpose of a specific override faster.

Answer (score 0):

Documenting the overloads individually does not violate DRY. DRY is not like a LWZ-compression scheme which compress all repeating substrings regardless of context. DRY is about a single canonical representation for a single piece of knowledge.

The different overloads of `copyOf()` are actually separate methods with separate implementations. They *happen* have the exact same blurb currently, but this is incidental. If the documentation had been written differently it might have gone into the specifics which differs between the overloads.

Comment: "They happen have the exact same blurb currently, but this is incidental" - this isn't incidental, this is because they have almost identical implementation - see the source code of Arrays.copyOf().

Comment: Sorry, but I don't believe this is incidental. Quite the opposite, it is pretty deliberate. See my comment below [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/429664).

Comment: @iwis: The key word is "almost". If they had the exact same implementation there would not be a need for multiple overloads in the first place. So there is *some* difference, and that difference may or may not be surfaced in the documentation.

Comment: @DocBrown: I'm sure they copy-pasted the same text. The point is the documentation for each overload does not describe the exact same thing since there are implementation differences. If the documentation had been more detailed the implementation details might have surfaced in the text. So the text are not equal by necessity, and therefore there is no DRY violation.

Comment: @JacquesB: The copyOf() methods simply copy a table. This operation doesn't depend on the type of elements in a way other than allocating other number of bytes per element (byte 1B, short 2B, int 4B, long 8B, char 2B, float 4B, double 8B, boolean 1B), which is obvious, and the default value of the element type, which can be inferred. Apart of this the implementations are exactly the same. So your sentence "They happen have the exact same blurb currently, but this is incidental" is incorrect.

Comment: @JacquesB: sure there are implementation differences - they are pretty obvious: the basic type of the array and their default values. Everything else is identical, and the OP is asking if in such a situation, where 95% of the method behaviour is the same, and only 5% different, it is a good idea to duplicate the docs in full, or if one can try to write the 95% of the docs only once, and duplicate only the 5% part.

Comment: @DocBrown: The question is why the overloads are needed. This is probably due to a limitation in Java. If it was implemented as a single generic method or macro, then it should also only have the documentation texts once. But since these are separate implementations it is not a violation of DRY to have separate documentation also.

Comment: @JacquesB: *"But since these are separate implementations"* - well, I did not look into the source, but from the OPs initial comment here, I assume the implentations themselves violate the DRY principle (intentionally), hence the docs do violate it, too.

Answer (score 0):

A computer doesn't care about how many levels it needs to dig into in order to access the thing it is interested in. A human, however, gets confused when they need to constantly look up things, even in the middle of sentences, to understand a part of that sentence.

In order to true-DRY your documentation, one specific overload of the copy method would only *directly* contain the information specific to that overload, and it would *link to* the more reusable parts of the documentation that would apply to multiple (or all) overloads of the copy method.

That's great and reusable, but it is a horrible reader experience. It breaks the flow of information by having the reader navigate to different pages, as opposed to reading one cohesive document.

The impact on the reader is so counterproductive that it is therefore better to compromise on the DRY so you can increase the actual educational quality of your documentation, **which is its main purpose**.

Similarly, even in code DRY violations are acceptable when pure DRY would cause other problems such as performance. E.g. in a web server backend scenario, in pure DRY, it would be preferable if the frontend were to retrieve an enum's possible values from the backend, so that there is only one source of the enum (i.e. the backend), as opposed to having the backend and frontend both define the enum.

*However*, that requires an extra network call. And that costs performance. And then you have to weigh if the performance cost outweighs the purity of your DRY. Barring more intricate solutions (for now), when the choice is between having the front and back end define their own enum, or having the frontend make web request to the backend to receive the enum; you'll generally prefer violating DRY in order to cut down on the extra web request (this is one of those "straw that broke the camel's back" type of situations).

However, as is the case with development, automation can really help give you best of both worlds. More intricate solutions can optimize the benefits you reap. For the enum example, you could generate the frontend enum based on the backend enum (using a template), to maximize both benefits (one source of enum information pre-compilation, *and* no network call needed at runtime).

For the documentation example, you could automatically load the linked information (i.e. the "base" copy documentation) in a panel on the page of the specific overload of the copy method; in a way that the user doesn't even notice that part of the page is being dynamically loaded from what is technically speaking another page/document.

That would be one possible solution to keep your DRY more pure, without negatively impacting the reader's experience.